Is it possible to remove pdf security to allow editing but still keep original format and bookmarks?
I've read another thread talking about ways to remove pdf security to allow copy and paste. However, methods like using Chrome also remove the bookmarks and potentially change the font. Is there any way to entirely preserve the original document (font, format, bookmarks) and just remove the editing security (without p/word) ? Preferably without uploading to online platforms. Thanks.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

No, there’s no easy way to bypass the security of most modern PDFs. It’s called security for a reason, and it’s specifically designed to stop people doing what you want to. I’m not saying that you’re criminal, but the PDF doesn’t know that.

No, security on a PDF is a one-way street, and if it were easy to circumvent or remove, it would not be "security".
"Removing" security usually means recreating the PDF, or using some brute-force method like capturing images (screenshots) which will necessarily lose any associated metadata.
For these reasons, there is not a way to remove security while retaining other document metadata.

There is nothing magical about PDF's if you can find an open source project that can read and write a particular format, it becomes trivial to remove security on the file - not all projects supports all features of the format, so depending upon the quality of the implementation you may lose some features but generally the general structure is preserved.

One could say there's nothing magical about decryption either.

With a lot of weak implementations, actually more true than you probably intended. However I don't think the OP was asking about encrypted content - just lockouts to prevent certain functions (editing/copying etc) the only reason those are called "security" is because thats what the marketing department decided to call them....

@KJ Yourself, myself and mkl are making the same point there is no security, quoting mkl: "Technically you have access to all the information in a PDF and can manipulate it arbitrarily whenever you have enough access to display it"

@DavidT yes most web sites dont understand that if the content is visible it must have been transmitted to client and decrypted into plain text with the given away key thus even if you have to resort, historically at worst to memory grabbing (not needed with modern PDF) it is in the users device thus users control

Q) ... any way to entirely preserve the original document (font, format, bookmarks) and just remove the editing security (without p/word) ? Preferably without uploading to online platforms.
Presuming you either have the password to open or there is none for opening "(without p/word)".
A) Yes of course it is so simple there are hundreds of sites HOWEVER to "open" the ONLY "secure" type of PDF you must have the password KEY to compare with the bunch of encryptions inside the now Unsecured PDF.
The one major collateral damage is signatures which you can then remove or replace. (See note at end)
From PDF Security White Paper as linked to by LockLizard who are honest enough to admit their own Screen DRM protection can be circumvented.
The bottom line is: 

1) Once you distribute a PDF file, the Master Password and restrictions can be removed.

2) Even when encrypted with a User Password, a PDF file can still have the Master Password, all restrictions, the User Password, and encryption removed from it **if you give anyone the User Password.**

3) PDF eBooks with DRM security (such as, but not limited to Web Buy, EBX, DocBox) offer no additional security at all, and all security can easily be removed.

This is usually combined with decompressing a PDF into its native TEXT state, thus the common method is look at qpdf. https://qpdf.sourceforge.io/

It is capable of performing transformations such as linearization, encryption, and decryption of PDF files.

Encryption Key

This refers to the actual key used by the encryption and decryption algorithms. It is distinct from the password. The main encryption key is generated at random and stored encrypted in the PDF file. The passwords used to protect a PDF file, if any, are used to protect the encryption key. This design makes it possible to use different passwords (e.g., user and owner passwords) to retrieve the encryption key or even to change the password on a file without changing the encryption key.


qpdf can expose the encryption key when run with the --show-encryption-key

Other commands to consider are --decrypt
Create an output file with no encryption even if the input file is encrypted. This option overrides the default behaviour of preserving whatever encryption was present on the input file.
and --remove-restrictions
Remove security restrictions associated with digitally signed PDF files. This may be combined with --decrypt to allow free editing of previously signed/encrypted files. This option invalidates and disables any digital signatures but leaves their visual appearances intact.
If you have a very old or not well secured PDF, then there are tools to attempt opening those early secured PDFs. One of those used by web sites for a "first look" will be based on http://www.guapdf.com/

Unlike most PDF password crackers, your PDF file is not altered in any way (except the decryption), even the file size is often the same.


Beware the demo may let you think ALL PDFs are insecure, However Adobe improved more recent "opener" passwords, and thus the time taken to open those without a simple "Pa5sVord" or favourite Sports name etc. can take years before eventually open. If NO password to open you can simply remove restrictions.

Since the file is electronic we can simply fiddle the dates to 2033 and change the names etc.

Answer
I does not matter if you need a password to open like this one or not.
What we need is to run the command:
qpdf -password=mypassword -decrypt Sample_Report.pdf derestriced.pdf

If you dont need a password to view then dont use one in the command.



Signatures are problematic as tied into the encryption. So not always easy to replace. Often they can be removed by open a PDF in an Office application like Word or Open/Libre Office. But that will be a conversion approach, needing their replacement. Simpler deletion in the raw PDF would be better. For more on that topic see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76569894/10802527

It is hard to tell if you are using sarcasm or being direct in your first sentence. Some explanation of how to use QPDF to accomplish what is requested would make this a better answer.

That's nice, but it doesn't improve your post to make it an answer.
